# stty equivalent in windows

Tags: linux, windows, serial-port, stty

Does anybody know an equivalent tool for stty on Windows? I want to reverse engineer serial port settings on a Windows platform.

I have to port a Windows application to a Linux platform, but I do not have any information on the serial port settings that I have to use for the application. I have to reverse engineer those settings. The most common ones don't work.

An example application on windows is available and working.

Comment: You can get COM port setting via serial sniffer like [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644), http://www.serialmon.com/ or http://www.hhdsoftware.com/serial-monitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. AFAIK there is no stty equivalent for Windows. I transitioned from Linux to Windows for work last year and have begrudgingly learned the "best practices" for Windows and how they differ from Linux.
2. The Device Manager in Windows should show you all serial port settings, but for specific port settings try `MODE.COM <PORT NAME>` as documented [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112841).

Good luck.

Comment: My problem is already solved. But this tool is really what I was looking for.